# Create Sql DB in C# Without Registering it in SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm currently looking into generating a local SQL DB with the following code:

```
using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
    using (var createCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE DBTitle ON PRIMARY "
        + "(NAME = DBName, "
        + "FILENAME = '" + fileLocation + "')"))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        createCommand.Connection = sqlConn;
        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
}
```

For a couple of reasons, I don't want this generated DB to be registered along with the rest of the DBs I see in Sql Server Manager. It adds an extra level of hassle when another system of constraints is placed on when/where you can put your cache file. Is there a way to generate the .mdf that I care about without going through registering it with my local data source?

Comment: What do you mean by "without going through registering it with my local data source"?  The only way to create an MDB file is with CREATE DATABASE.  You can subsequently detach it.

Comment: What? I think you are asking if you can somehow have a database on your server that you can't see in the list of databases or something along those lines. The answer to that is NO, of course not. I supposed you could create your database and then detach it. But what is the point of that?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That sounds perfect.

Comment: @SeanLange The reason is that this cache is likely to be passed around from person to person. Having to register it to use it or running into naming conflicts when selecting somebody else's is a hassle I don't want.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by cache. It is a database. And passing around a database file is a really bad idea. That is a sign that something is very wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange ... I am unsure exactly what you believe the difference in this case to be. I am using a SQL DB to cache data over multiple runs of my program. If you have further criticisms or suggestions, please give a reason. Saying that something "is a really bad idea" gives me nothing to go off of.

Comment: Why not store the data in a single database? Then you can easily view each run or whatever in a collection. That would be a lot simpler than creating many copies of the database. I have a feeling though that you are using the database for doing something quite different than a typical usage. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147983/discussion-between-dornadigital-and-sean-lange).